# Dynamic image inconsistencies in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, crystal-reports

I have developed an automated web service that generates pdf, word and excel reports using SAP's Crystal reports SDK. At one point in the past the need for dynamic images (specifically, photos) came up, so that feature was implemented in the following way:

- Images are pulled from a static directory, resized to specific dimensions based on the aspect ratio (e.g. 4:3 images are manually resized to 800x600) and placed in a new subfolder. The resizing is done with the following method:

  ```
  private Bitmap ResizeImage(Bitmap image, int width, int height) {
      var destRect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
      var destImage = new Bitmap(width, height);
      destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, 
      image.VerticalResolution);
      using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage)) {
          graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
          graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
          graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
          graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
          graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
          using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes()) {
              wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
              graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, 
              image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
          }
      }
      return destImage;
  }
  ```
- All images placed in that subfolder have their full path entered as a Crystal Reports custom object collection datasource (there are 10 string variables for up to 10 photos, as well as some other variables for other images, all with their own placeholder image objects in suppressed sections).
- In the report, placeholder images in suppressed sections have the variable that contains the image path in their "Graphic Location" formula. if the variable entered in the graphic location is a valid path from an image that exists, the section is unsuppressed programmatically and the placeholder image is replaced with the image in the directory.

The problem: Let's take 4:3 images in word format (.doc) as an example. Two images that are resized to 800x600, with the above method, with the same file extension (.jpg), entered in the same rpt file and indeed using the same placeholder image object with the same settings (I have set all placeholder images to 0.7 X & Y scaling in the CR Designer) show up completely differently across reports. One 4:3 image might take up about 50-60% of a page (in the exported document), whereas another image with effectively the same settings might be so large it spills over to two or three more pages.

My question: Is this a well-known or documented issue with crystal reports, or is there a different part of the process I've described that causes this inconsistency? 
Are there any known workarounds in the case of it being a CR issue?

I look forward to everyone's replies, as well as any feedback on what I've described.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the static images that are used as the dummy placeholders for the dynamic ones are NOT resized. They should be inserted from images that are already the desired size.

If that was not the issue, please provide a sample of the rpt.

By the way, you can create resized versions of images on the fly within Crystal using a UFL.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply. I temporarily changed the X&Y scaling of the placeholders to 1 and the problem persisted.
Here's a link to my report template: https://mega.nz/#!IxIFxC7C!jqAORqy2I8CpGTq9jrwOf7u8ucOViV4zyxQNQD2SBRs

Comment: The key point was not about changing the x&y scaling.
It was about not changing the image object size once inserted into the report.

Comment: I see, so you mean the placeholder image should, for example, have static dimensions of 800x600 in the case of 800x600 images ? If so, that might be too hard to implement as the placeholder is replaced by images of all kinds of dimensions

Comment: I'd further like to add, if you are referring to the image remaining static _after_ it has replaced the placeholder image, that is already happening. All resizing is done **before** images are placed in the report.